# Remove margins between container for border-spacing?

Tags: css

Im using display table and table-cell to make some list items line up horizontally. The content is dynamic so the text length in each li and the number of li's will change.

Im using border-spacing to create a margin between the li's, however I dont a margin between the first li and its containing ul, or between the last li and the ul.

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  <p>Other content </p>
</div> 

div {
  background: grey;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 5px;
}
li {
  display: table-cell;
  background: gold;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rHDys

[image]

Comment: Is the display table and table-cell for the layout a must have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the trick using borders, I've created a small demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rHosz

```
div {
  background: grey;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
li {
  display: table-cell;
  background: gold;
  border-left: 5px solid grey;
}
li:first-child{
  border-left: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but you could do the following:

```
ul {
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    width: calc(100% + 10px);
    border-spacing: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer uses CSS3, and it might not be compatible or supported with older browsers.

```
div {
  background: grey;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
li {
  display: table-cell;
  background: gold;
  border-right: 5px solid grey;
  border-top: 5px solid grey;
}
li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
```

See sample: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rqzkJ

Comment: Just a quick note. IE7 and IE8 don't support `last-child`, but they support `first-child`. You just have to switch the code around to change the first one instead of the last one.

Comment: Good answer from Arbel!

Answer (score -2):

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  <p>Other content </p>
</div> 

div {
  background: grey;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 5px;
}
li {
  display: table-cell;
  background: gold;
}
```

**border-spacing: 5px;** remove this